# Excel custom function to look up a date code

Tags: excel, vba, collections, number-formatting

I wrote a function to look up a serial date code from a static collection.  Below is a small snippet from the function.

```
Function Dcode(IntNum as Integer)

set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add 101, 40544
dict.Add 102, 40575
dict.Add 103, 40603
dict.Add 104, 40634
dict.Add 105, 40664

Dcode = FormatDateTime(dict(IntNum),vbShortDate)

End Function
```

The code works and for instance if 101 is in cell A1, and in B1 the formula below is entered:

```
=Dcode(A1)
```

The result is 1/1/2011, which is correct.  However the cell number format is General and if you try and filter by date, you cannot because each date is listed individually instead of by year, month, day.  Can anyone help with changing the cell format before the function ends?

I tried adding at the beginning of the function:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
```

This did not work, actually seemed to do nothing. Also to add some clarification, I am looking to create a global function when complete so hopefully this can be completed without saving as a .xlsm file

Comment: The problem is that your function output is a String (technically the output is a Variant that is coerced into a String) because the `FormatDateTime` method results in a String, not an actual date (which requires the dateserial).  To correct this, don't format the output and specify that your function output is a date and just set it to the desired dateserial.  Then you can format the cell to a desired date format and still be able to filter it as dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, this is how you would do it:

```
Function Dcode(IntNum As Integer) As Date

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add 101, 40544
dict.Add 102, 40575
dict.Add 103, 40603
dict.Add 104, 40634
dict.Add 105, 40664

Dcode = CDate(dict(IntNum))

End Function
```

Comment: This did work partially, the result for 101 comes back as 40544, but once converted to to date format, it is able to be filtered based on year, month, day.  Just need to convert the number to a date.

Comment: Formatting is handled on the sheet itself, not within functions.  This is true even for native Excel functions.  You'd have to write a separate sub that does the formatting if you don't want to do it manually, like what DisplayName has proposed.

Comment: Usually, a particular formula is limited to a specific section of the sheet, like "column A will have values and column B will be the formula" then you can just select column B and apply the desired cell format so that all cells in column B will be formatted as date.  Then put in your formula and the cells will already have the desired format.  That example is a very standard setup, it's unusual to have the VBA do it for you without some specific reason or need.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation.  This will do the trick, just have to format the column in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of some code you can put in the function and format the calling cell

while you can place the following in the worksheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If InStr(Target.Formula, "=DCode") > 0 Then Target.NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: But then the workbook would have to be a .xlsm file.  I am hoping to just make this a global function once completed.

Comment: I must confirm I'm not aware of a "not xlsm" solution. While your question didn't mention such a requirement at all so if my answer works you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you. unless some other solution comes in...

Comment: I will update my question, however the solution you presented did not work as the number format remains "General"

Comment: funny, in my test it worked. more important: _"chameleon"_ questions are not well received. they tend to make helpful people waste time